# Linux Netfilter: Enqueue packets to the user-space before defragment

Tags: linux-kernel, iptables, netfilter, ip-fragmentation

The question is: How can I enqueue packets to the user-space with netfilter NFQUEUE *before* *de*fragment?

According to [Linux kernel source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_defrag_ipv4.c?v=3.19), `nf_defrag_ipv4` is installed in `NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING` (known as PREROUTING in iptables/nftables) and `NF_INET_LOCAL_OUT` (OUTPUT).

So I tried the following anti-defrag nftables filter (original: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638753/5167443) for `NF_INET_LOCAL_OUT`, but I'm still getting *de*fragmented packets.

```
sudo nft add table filter
sudo nft add chain filter predefrag { type filter hook output priority -- -450 \; }
sudo nft add filter predefrag skuid nfqhooked counter queue num 42
```

In the above filter, `-450` stands for a priority that precedes `NF_IP_PRI_CONNTRACK_DEFRAG=-400`. i.e., the filter is expected to work before `nf_defrag_ipv4`.

I'm using Linux 3.19 (Ubuntu 15.04) and [this my own binding](https://github.com/osrg/earthquake/blob/9f7e6efa0030aca66918dbd7928117bc8f850ab2/pyearthquake/middlebox/internal/nfq.py) for `libnetfilter_queue.so.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just resolved by myself.

I had misunderstood that netfilter handles TCP reassembly that is actually handled by "TCP Auto Corking".

Now I can get fragmented (i.e. non-corked) packets by just writing `0` to `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_autocorking`.

http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=f54b311142a92ea2e42598e347b84e1655caf8e3